# Click function not registering correctly in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that should be triggered on click of productid...

```
$("[id^='productid']").click(function(){
            var numberPattern = /\d+/g;
            match = this.id.match(numberPattern)
        })
```

The products are generated using Jquery pagination as given below....

```
function createproducts(jsondata){
            transactiondata = jsondata
            $("<div id='product-container'></div>").appendTo("#product-list");
            $('#pagination').pagination({
             items: jsondata.length
            ,itemsOnPage: 12
            ,onInit:redrawData
            ,onPageClick: redrawData
            ,cssStyle: 'light-theme'});
        }

        function redrawData(pageNumber,event){
            if (pageNumber) {
                slicedata = transactiondata.slice(pageNumber*12,
                        Math.min((pageNumber+1)*12,transactiondata.length));
            }
            else {
                slicedata = transactiondata.slice(0,12) 
            }

            $("#product-container").empty()
            slicedata.forEach(function(e,i,a){
                var obj = e;
                $("<div id = productid" + i + " class = product-cards </div>").appendTo('#product-container')
                //-working$("<div id='product" + i + "left'  class='product-cards-left' style='background-image:url(  " + imagepath_start + obj.image_caption + ")'> </div>").appendTo('#product' + i);
                //lightbox is the jquery plugin that we use..The below line is very sensitive...
                //-lightbox working$("<a href= " + imagepath_start + obj.image_caption + " data-lightbox="+ imagepath_start + obj.image_caption+"> <div id='product" + i + "left'  class='product-cards-left' style='background-image:url(  " + imagepath_start + obj.image_caption + ")' > </div></a>").appendTo('#product' + i);
                $("<div id='product" + i + "left'  class='product-cards-left' style='background-image:url(  " + imagepath_start + obj.image_caption + ")'> </div>").appendTo('#productid' + i);
                $("<div id = product" + i + "right class = product-cards-right> </div>").appendTo('#productid' + i   )
                $("<label><b>  Price: <b></label>  <label>" + '$' + obj.price + "</label><br>").appendTo('#product' + i +"right"   )
                $("<label><b>  Old Price: <b></label>  <label>" + '$' + obj.old_price + "</label><br>").appendTo('#product' + i +"right"   )
                $("<label><b>  Author Name: <b></label>  <label>" + obj.author_name + "</label>").appendTo('#product' + i +"right"   )
                $("<div id= elementid style='display:none' >"+ obj.id+" </div>").appendTo('#product' + i +"right"   )
                //$("<label>" + obj.name + "</label>").appendTo('#product' + i +"right"   )
            })
```

Problem:-

When I click the productid the click function is correctly working and calculates "match" correctly..But once I move to next page(Onpageclick is triggered) and click productid, the click function is not working anymore..Why would this happen?

Comment: When you page past the first, you need to re-add the click handler, or use a delegate like `$.on()` from a static parent and use the second selector argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(document)` handler so that your click handler is not lost.

```
$(document).on("click", "[id^='productid']", function(){
        var numberPattern = /\d+/g;
        match = this.id.match(numberPattern)
    });
```

Comment: FYI: It's not a "`$(document)` handler". It's a delegated event handler attached to the `document` element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a delegated event handler like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "[id^='productid']", function(){
    var numberPattern = /\d+/g;
    match = this.id.match(numberPattern)
});
```

It works by listening for events bubbled up to a non-changing ancestor element, *then* applying the jQuery selector on the chain of elements that caused the event, *then* applies the function to *any matching elements* that caused the event.

You would normally attached the delegated event to the nearest non-changing ancestor element, but the fallback is `document` if nothing is convenient to use. Do not ever use `body` for delegated events as it has a bug with some events (due to styling).

Answer (score 0):

When you change the page you lose the hook jquery adds on the DOM which is triggering the click. Just recall the method that listens to clicks on page change.